pm2 setup command stops at the first step. How to make it work?
I call the command "pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js staging setup" and its execution stops at the "hook pre-setup" stage. The SSH key of my ec2 container is added to the repository and git clone works. pm2 is installed on the server and it is the same version as on the local computer. The pem key is valid and the ssh connection works.
My ecosystem file:
const commands = [
  'cd /home/ubuntu/app/current',
  'npm ci',
  'npm run prepare:env',
  'npm run build',
  'pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.config.js --env production',
];
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'myproj',
      script: 'npm run start',
      autorestart: true,
      max_restarts: 50,
      max_memory_restart: '900M',
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
  ],
  // Deployment Configuration
  deploy: {
    staging: {
      key: './key.pem',
      user: 'ubuntu',
      host: 'my-ec2.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
      ssh_options: 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no',
      ref: 'origin/staging',
      repo: 'git@github.com:mygit/mygit.git',
      path: '/home/ubuntu/app',
      'post-deploy': commands.join(' && '),
    },
  },
};

I reinstalled pm2 on the server and on the local computer. Cleaned out the .pm2 folder. Nothing helps. And there are no errors, just a command waiting endlessly.
